# Chrome settings window doesn't fit on netbook screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

I'd really like to use chrome on my netbook, but I can't change the settings because the resolution is 1024*600 on Windows 7.

Is there any workaround? I tried the move window command with keyboard thinking that I could move the window up out of the screen enough for the ok button to appear, but the window always snaps back to screen so I can't press ok to save my settings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try force resizing or moving the window using one of these apps:

- [AltMove](http://www.deskex.com/Altmove/index.asp)

> - The moving - You can move windows and controls which do not support this ability.
> - The resizing - You can resize windows and controls which do not support this ability.

- [WinSizeMe](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2339650,00.asp)

> WinSizeMe can set a window's size – the width and height of the window

I have used AltMove on a netbook in the past for resizing an app which didn't allow itself to be resized and I couldn't use it without making it bigger. Though this is not what you want to do, you may find that one of these apps can do the job you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, AltMove is great and solves my problem, even though it might not be the solution I was expecting

Answer (score 1):

There is no kosher workaround, but someone has posted a patch at google code:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18949#c62

If you're comfortable compiling a chromium installation, then you have a solution. If not, Tab is your friend.

Comment: Tab? Is it a program? It's such a common word that it is hard to google

Comment: Tab is the key named "Tab" on your keyboard. One of Tab key's uses is to switch to the next option in a window, form, application, etc.

Comment: Yeah I know what key it is :P I just thought it might be a program because it was capitalised :)

Answer (score 0):

If the window is only a little bit too large, try going to full-screen view om Chrome to see more. (You press F11, I think.)

EDIT: I misunderstood the situation, sorry. Here's the quick fix I use:

On my Asus Netbook, I have it set up so I can press ctrl-alt and the arrow keys to rotate the screen (in the Intel GMA driver control panel). Pressing Ctrl-alt-right arrow sets the screen "sideways" (e.g., portrait mode) will display the bottom of the Chrome settings/options screen. Using the trackpad like this is weird, but you should have all the software you need for this if you have an Asus or netbook with a similar setup.

If you need something less awkward, the AltMove answer might work better.

Comment: The settings window is a normal dialog, not a browser window.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct! Have added to my original answer.